# Tracking Email when they Click Using PHP

Tags: php, email, tracking, newsletter

I am in need of a some help if possible. What I want to do is: Send Newsletter, then I want to Track who "clicked on the ads" and auto link to the website URL.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
<?php
if( $_GET["email"]) { echo $_GET["email"];}
$email = $_GET["email"];
$page = $_GET["page"];
mysql_connect("localhost", "dbname", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());
$redirect = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
$page_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracking_table (`email`, `rec_use_date`) VALUES ('$email', now())") or die(mysql_error());
header("Location:$redirect");exit; 
?>
```

What I have will save to the database, but won't redirect to the URL:

```
http://www.malaysiastreet.com/tracking/getopen.php?email=youremail@yahoo.com&page=http://www.google.com
```

Comment: There will be some thing as out put before header. you can use ob_start(); on top of the page and please use PDO or mysqli (parametrized queries)

Comment: drop the echo $_GET["email"]; line 2

Answer (score 0):

Please try a space after the :

change

```
header("Location:$redirect");
```

to

```
header("Location: " . $redirect);
```

Also when you put on the website please use `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_`

Comment: Thank you for your help, after I change the code use "mysqli_"
still same : I can track the email, but won't redirect to the LINK.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]);` to get the URl of the user..**

> Use this code...

```
<?php

$return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //return url

if( $_GET["email"]) { echo $_GET["email"];}
$email = $_GET["email"];
$page = $_GET["page"];
mysql_connect("localhost", "dbname", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());
$redirect = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
$page_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tracking_table (`email`, `rec_use_date`) VALUES ('$email', now())") or die(mysql_error());
//to return the user URl
header('Location:'.$return_url);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, after I used your code. still same : I can track the email, but won't redirect to the LINK.

Comment: Don't use `exit()` function or change `header('Location:'.$return_url);` to `header("Location:login.php");` and if both does not works use **JavaScript to redirect** like `<script language="javascript"> window.location="login.php"; </script>`

Comment: thank you for your code, yes can do in this way, but the link is auto from newsletter (I means is : each JPG will different link, will set it in the target="URL")